# Ubuntu 14.04 + Virtual Box and CorelDraw

Tags: virtualbox

I have Win7/Ubuntu dual boot. I have no reason to use Win anymore, except CorelDRAW which is a must, I'm bored of switching between these two.

My plan is to install Ubuntu on 24GB SSD (20GB for /root, 4GB for /swap), and 500GB SATA to set as /home. After that, need to install VirtualBox, set up Win7 and install CorelDRAW.

Is that possible? Important thing is that VirtualBox + Windows + CorelDRAW must be on /home, because theres only 20GB on /root.

Comment: I'm not sure what version of CorelDRAW you're using, but some of them appear to work OK in Wine, so that might be something to look into... https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=440

Comment: I'm on X6 right now, but X4 should be lowest version.

Comment: Those are all classified as 'garbage' as far as working with Wine, so that's definitely not your best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an aside, I'd recommend putting your `swap` on your HDD rather than your SSD - this is for two main reasons:

1. 4 GB of a 24 GB drive is a large percentage. SSDs run best when you're using below a certain percentage of their storage (I think the number is around 80%)
2. Lots of writes from the swap, which will likely lead to degradation of the hard drive faster

As for the rest of it, you should be good to go. Virtualbox lets you put the windows 7 virtual hard drive wherever you please.

Comment: Thanks musher. I'll make swap on HDD.

So Win7 can go on /home, that's important. 

Now all I need is to find solution how to convert my NTFS partition to EXT4 (/home) without loosing Data.

Comment: Which partition is made in NTFS? Your best bet is likely to just make a backup of all the files and replace them.

Comment: On HDD there are - C: (Windows) and D: (Data) and both are NTFS. I would like to merge them, and convert to EXT4 for /home and /swap. SSD is for /root.

Answer (score -1):

If what you are asking is "Is it possible to put /home on a different disk than /root?" then yes, that is possible.

I'm not very familiar with VirtualBox, but according to [this](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Guest_OSes) article, it should work just fine.

One such way to install /home and /root on separate partitions can be found here: http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/installseparatehome
From what I can tell it answers your question. 
It appears to be a little out-dated, but it looks like it will still work.